# How to enable depth test with QOpenGLWidget? It renders black screen

Tags: opengl, c++, depth-buffer, qt, depth

Currently I am writing a small application with Qt and OpenGl and I choosed `QOpenGLWidget` for rendering graphics.

That's how I declared my widget:

```
class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions{
     // Methods, slots, e.t.c
}
```

And that's the constructor:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    /* Tried this, it didn't help.
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    this->setFormat(format);
    */
}
```

In my init function I set `GL_CULL_FACE` and `GL_DEPTH_TEST`:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    /* Some initialization stuff regarding the scene */

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

}
```

And I really don't know why the widget renders the black screen.
Here are some pictures.
First one: with disabled `GL_CULL_FACE` and disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`.
[image]

Second one: with enabled `GL_CULL_FACE` and disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. Maybe it's not a good picture, but I can assure you, you can see some surfaces through the other.
[image]

Third one: with enabled `GL_CULL_FACE` and enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. Actually, it doesn't matter if `GL_CULL_FACE` is enabled. Anyway it renders the black screen.
[image]

And here's the image without any shading just to show you that the model is fine.
[image]

I tried to set the format manually, but it didn't help. Still the black screen:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
this->setFormat(format);
```

Oh and yes, I set `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` at the beginning of my `paintGL()` function.

Comment: By the way, if I try to set the version with `format.setVersion(3, 2);`, it also renders the black screen. I am not sure, but I think it's somehow related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please give a complete source code of (small error-prone version of) your project, because this kind of problem depends on lots of things.

However, there are lots of reasons that can make unwanted black screen, most common mistakes that I can guess in your case, are:

- mathematics mistakes

  - camera matrix (in your case see your clipping range)
  - shader mistakes
- scissor test (check if your scissor is correctly working)
- soon or late clearing of framebuffer

Comment: We typically ask users to post their code here, and not having it uploaded somewhere else, mainly for 3 reasons: 1) we're lazy and don't want to do extra steps to see the core of the question, 2) expect the user to narrow down the location of the issue and 3) external sources _may_ become invalid, and thus make the question no longer relevant. Thus you should ask them to add more code to the question (please do it in the comments of the question), but not to upload their code somewhere.

Comment: tnx for your tips

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour Yeah, you are right. There was a bug with projection matrix.